# Customizing MUI TextField spin button

Tags: html, css, reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I'm trying to customize the way up/down spin buttons look in MUI TextField.
[image: Image 1]

I'm trying to make the arrows white and the surrounding area all black and a bit bigger, like this:
[image: Image 2]

I understand I need to change `input::-webkit-outer-spin-button, input::-webkit-inner-spin-button`, but I cannot figure out which properties to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass the props directly in the `TextField` component via the `sx` prop:

```
    <TextField
        type="number"
        sx={{
          "input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button": {
            ...spinnerStyles
          },
          "input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button": {
            ...spinnerStyles
          }
        }}
      />
```

Or you can pass them via the `TextField`'s `InputProps` prop, like so:

```
    <TextField
        type="number"
        InputProps={{
          type: "number",
          sx:{
            "input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button": {
              ...spinnerStyles
            },
            "input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button": {
              ...spinnerStyles
            }
          }
        }}
      />
```

### Edit for requested styling

To style the spinner buttons themselves [and their background], you can [base64 encode your PNG](https://onlinepngtools.com/convert-png-to-base64) button image and embed that as the background of the spinner itself (or you can link it to an external image file):

```
const spinnerStyles = {
  "-webkit-appearance": "none",
  background:
    "#000 url(data:image/png;base64,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) no-repeat center center",
  width: "2em",
  opacity: 1,
  position: "absolute",
  top: 0,
  right: 0,
  bottom: 0,
  overflow: "hidden",
  borderTopRightRadius: "0.25rem",
  borderBottomRightRadius: "0.25rem"
};
```

You can style the rest of the TextField with your existing styles/theme -- I just took the image you provided as an example.

Output:

[image: image of formatted spinners]

Working [Updated] CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/romantic-knuth-j0n5lw?file=/demo.tsx:961-1290

Comment: Thanks Steve, perhaps I need to be more precise. I understand how to pass css, I just cannot figure out how to get the look and feel on the picture.

Comment: @GRZa Ah my bad -- I thought you were asking which TextField props to use.  I've updated my answer.